# Bokeh: First dot connected to last dot

Tags: bokeh

I have a line chart

```
ts_chart = figure(plot_width=700, plot_height=400, tools=[hovertool, SaveTool()], x_axis_type='datetime')
ts_chart.line(x_field,y_field,source=source, line_color=color,)
```

but for some reason the last dot is connected to the first dot.

[image]

Any ideas what could cause this.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I also checked the dataframe that is used as source and the dates are in the correct order.

Comment: Try duplicating the last element from x and y like `x_field.append(x_field[-1])`

Comment: None of the projects docs or examples exhibit this occurrence. But if your data does not contain the duplicated point, then this must be a bug of some sort. Please post a report with a complete, minimal, runnable test case to investigate in the issue tracker: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues

Comment: @tenticon did you ever manage to figure this out? I'm having this same issue with BokehJS